# Eliminar registros de una tabla con ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy aprendiendo a usar la función Ajax y necesito crear un método para eliminar registros de una tabla pulsando la `[X]` que se genera con cada registro creado en una tabla (la cual se despliega automáticamente al realizar un registro).

El problema radica es que cuando pulso la `[X]`, se eliminan todos los registros. Cumple con su función de borrar, pero no de la forma esperada.

Aquí el script de JQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnRegistrar").click(function(){
      var parametros = {
        "rut": $("#txtRut").val(),
        "nombre": $("#txtNombre").val(),
        "apellido": $("#txtApellido").val(),
        "fecha_nac": $("#txtFecha").val(),
        "fono": $("#txtFono").val(),
        "direccion": $("#txtDireccion").val()
      };

      $.ajax({
        data : parametros,
        url : 'registrar.php',
        type : 'post',
        beforeSend : function(){
          $("#cuadro").html("<img src='img/loading.gif' width='400px' height='400px'/>");
        },
        success : function(aviso){
          $("#cuadro").html(aviso);
        }
      });
    });

    $('#btnBorrar').click(function(){
      var param = {
        "rut": $("#txtRut").val(),
        "nombre": $("#txtNombre").val(),
        "apellido": $("#txtApellido").val(),
        "fecha_nac": $("#txtFecha").val(),
        "fono": $("#txtFono").val(),
        "direccion": $("#txtDireccion").val()
      };

      $.ajax({
        data : param,
        url : 'registrar.php',
        type : 'post',
        beforeSend : function(){
          $("#cuadro").html("<img src='img/loading.gif' width='400px' height='400px'/>");
        },
        success : function(advice){
          $("#cuadro").html(advice);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Y el código php:

```
  <?php
  // ********************************************* //
    $rut = $_POST["rut"];
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $fecha_nac = $_POST["fecha_nac"];
    $fono = $_POST["fono"];
    $direccion = $_POST["direccion"];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "clientes";

    // ********************************************* //

    // Conexión a la DB //

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // INSERTAR REGISTRO //
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente
    VALUES('$rut', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$fecha_nac', '$fono', '$direccion')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "<h3>Sus datos han sido registrados correctamente</h3>";
    } else{
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    // FIN INSERTAR REGISTRO //

    // LISTAR REGISTROS //
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      echo "<table border='1px'>
      <tr>
        <th>RUT</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
        <th>Dirección</th>
      </tr>";
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row["rut"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["nombre"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["apellido"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["fecha_nac"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["fono"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["direccion"]."</td>
        <td><input type='button' value=' [ X ] ' id='btnBorrar'></td>
      </tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    } else{
      echo "Aún no hay registros<br>";
    }
    // FIN LISTAR REGISTROS //

    // BORRAR REGISTROS //
    $sql = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rut";

    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
      echo "Registro eliminado";
    } else{
      echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    // FIN BORRAR REGISTROS //

    $conn->close();
  ?>
```

También adjunto imagen del formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué hice mal con el método para borrar registros?

Comment: Esta instrucción SQL esta incompleta: `"DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rut";` ¿dónde esta el valor (*tal vez un id*) que llega del frontend para verificar cuál de todos los registros eliminar?

Comment: Saludos. En la parte del `DELETE` el `WHERE` solo tiene `rut` (no sabemos si es un numero o texto); así que te hace falta completarle con el `$rut` cuyo valor lo obtienes en la línea `$rut = $_POST["rut"];`. Adicionalmente te comento que debes depurar tu código; no es necesario envies siempre todos los datos; por ejemplo si en tu BD `rut` es único en cada fila de la tabla, bastara con que envíes solo este para eliminar.

Comment: Corregí el error y ha funcionado. Gracias por orientarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te han comentado el problema radica en la query de borrado

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rut";
```

En este caso borrará todos los registros donde `rut` no se nulo.

Seguramente la consulta que buscas es

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rut = '" + $rut + "'";
```

Pero hay que asegurarse de que `rut` sea único, sino borrarías varios registros que pueden no estar relacionados. Para asegurarse que rut es único puedes definirlo en la tabla como `PRIMARY KEY` o puedes definirla como `UNIQUE`.
Si el valor no es único siempre puedes definir un campo `id` que sea PRIMARY KEY de tu tabla y usar ese internamente para el borrado.

Sin embargo la consulta que te he puesto arriba tiene un problema. Ese problema se llama SQL Injection y es una de las vulnerabilidades mas comunes en web dev.

Dado que cualquiera puede llamar a `registrar.php` que pasaría si hiciéramos una llamada a mano pasando `' OR '1'='1` ?

Si construímos la consulta final nos quedará:

```
DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rut = '' OR '1'='1'
```

Dado que `'1'='1'` siempre es true todas las columnas se borrarán. Aunque se pueden hacer cosas peores con este ataque que borrar tus datos ;) ([más info sobre SQL injections](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection))

Lo que tenemos que hacer es utilizar [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) para escapar los inputs quedando la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM cliente WHERE rut = '" + mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $rut) + "'";
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Muy educativo y claro su comentario.